# Python beautiful soup showing same result for each page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the titles off each page of the steam free to play search results using python 3.5 and beautiful soup. However the results returned are just the titles on the first page and not on the subsequent pages:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

titles_list=[]

for i in range(3):      # Number of pages plus one 
    print(i)
    url = 'http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Free%20to%20Play/?tab=MostPlayed#p' + str(i)
    print(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

    titles=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"tab_item_name"})

    for item in titles:
         try:
              name=item.text
         except:
              name='sdfsd'   

         print(name)
         titles_list.append(name)
```

Console Results (I know 0 and 1 are the same but i=2 should show a different set of games):

```
0
http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Free%20to%20Play/?tab=MostPlayed#p0
Dota 2
Team Fortress 2
Warframe
Clicker Heroes
Unturned
Path of Exile
War Thunder
SMITE
Trove
AdVenture Capitalist
1
http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Free%20to%20Play/?tab=MostPlayed#p1
Dota 2
Team Fortress 2
Warframe
Clicker Heroes
Unturned
Path of Exile
War Thunder
SMITE
Trove
AdVenture Capitalist
2
http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Free%20to%20Play/?tab=MostPlayed#p2
Dota 2
Team Fortress 2
Warframe
Clicker Heroes
Unturned
Path of Exile
War Thunder
SMITE
Trove
AdVenture Capitalist
```

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the underlying GET request which fetches the data, that is more reliable for parsing as you don't get the details which are rendered by javascript using the actual page's url.

Using firebug, I found the underlying GET request to be (2nd page):

> http://store.steampowered.com/search/tabpaginated/render/?query=&start=10&count=10&genre=37&tab=MostPlayed&cc=IN&l=english

And from there, used the below script to get all the titles from all 32 pages.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

for i in range(0, 32):
    start_count = i * 10;
    jsonResponse = requests.get("http://store.steampowered.com/search/tabpaginated/render/"
                                "?query=&start="+str(start_count)+"&count=10&genre=37&tab=MostPlayed&cc=IN&l=english")
    data = json.loads(jsonResponse.text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["results_html"], "html.parser")
    alltitles = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': re.compile('tab_item_name')})
    for title in alltitles:
        print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens here is that the list that starts with "Dota 2" is always loaded on original request to http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Free%20to%20Play/?tab=MostPlayed.

You can check it in your browser's developer tools that this is always loaded first, regardless of the number after #p. This is also what your `requests.get(url).content` gets.

If you refresh the url with #p2 at the end in your browser, you can sometimes see the first list for a split second before the other list is displayed.

I'm not sure after quickly looking into it what loads the other list but it must be something happening after the request is made.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, a `#` fragment is a page-internal client-side anchor, and not actually passed to the server. Client-side JavaScript frequently uses this for various purposes, so that's probably what's happening here.  You'll need to run or simulate the JavaScript on the page client-side to get subsequent results.